# when I update ruby to 2.0.0-p0, my vim can't work

Tags: ruby, vim, rvm

I'm not sure what caused this, but I did these:

1. rvm requirements

   I did this `brew install  autoconf automake  libtool pkg-config openssl readline libyaml sqlite libxml2 libxslt libksba`
2. `rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p0`

then, when I type `vim`, it shows like this:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/Daniel-Xu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib
>
> Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/vim
>
> Reason: image not found
>   Trace/BPT trap: 5

I have googled about this, but I'm not sure they were the same like my situation, so I'm very appreciated for everyone's help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `vim` addons/settings require `ruby` to prettify your `.rb`-files editing experience. It wants to load `1.9.3` (according to dyld’s error message). First of all, let’s see which ruby versions are available on your machine:

```
~ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.3-p327 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.0.0-preview2 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

On my machine there are two rubies and `2.0.0` is the default one. OK, let’s use `1.9.3` with vim:

```
~ rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p327 && vim
```

This should apply a monkey-fix and resuscitate your vim. But the problem is definitely deeper and seems to be caused by one of your vim addons, possibly incompatible with `2.0.0` (scarcely), or requiring some additional gems to be installed for `ruby 2.0.0`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using homebrew you should be able to reinstall vim to get it to compile and link with your currently installed libraries.

```
brew uninstall --force vim
brew install vim
```

Answer (score 2):

If you got your Vim from homebrew, chances are it's built against a specific version of Ruby (1.9.3). The official MacVim binary download shouldn't care about your Ruby version.

Some people have had troubles with Command-T, too, for what it's worth.